# How many $7$-letter sequences are there with at least six different letters? exactly five different letters?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many $7$- letter sequences are there if:

(1.) there are at least $6$ different letters

(2.) exactly $5$ different letters

( out of $7$ positions for both as mentioned above)

what should be my approach?

Comment: As usual, please try to write your approach/attempt.
Anyway, think about the set of all the letters and the how many you can pick from them. Then think about repetition.

Comment: Do I use both comb and perm? Sth like for part a): C (26,8)*C(25,7)*C(24,6)*C(23,5)*(22,4)*C(21,3)*C(26,1)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

1) For "at least" and "no more than" statements it is a good approach to subtract the undesired ones (the complement set so to say) from all possible combinations

2) In this case you will have $2$ similar characters, look up [permutations of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)

**PS**: Try to add as much context to your question as possible i.e. what you have tried, where are you stuck, *what alphabet are we using here* for this particular question. We are here to learn, educate and share ideas and the community will receive questions without an effort in a bad way.

---

Edit:

@jl00 may have a point in the comments

There are $2$ cases

- $6$ different letters
- $7$ different letters

For case one: you will need to figure out in how many ways you can choose these $6$ letters. One of them will be repeated, in how many ways can you choose this repeated one? How many ways can you arrange these letters?

Comment: Wouldn't it be far easier to just do the two cases in problem 1?

Comment: Do I use both comb ? Sth like for part a): C (26,8)*C(25,7)*C(24,6)*C(23,5)*(22,4)*C(21,3)*C(26,1)

Comment: @Rishika for a) you can also try to think of it as with 6 different letters or (+) with 7 different letters.